# Mouse clicks to add objects in GLUT program?

Tags: opengl

My program displays an image and text when it is compiled. I am trying to add/modify objects each time I click the left or right button of the mouse. I am trying to loop it so every time i click the mouse button something is added or moved. I tried it but after the second click nothing appears.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<Gl/gl.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>

int n;
int m;
int onMouse = 1;
int *image;
void *font = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12;

void mouseClicks(int button, int state, int x, int y) 
{
     if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
        onMouse++;

}

void output(int x, int y, char *string)
{
  int len, i;

  glRasterPos2f(x, y);
  len = (int) strlen(string);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
  {
    glutBitmapCharacter(font, string[i]);
  }
}

void Time1 ()
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.8,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(230.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,845.0);
        glVertex2f(230.0,845.0);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(230.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,845.0);
        glVertex2f(230.0,845.0);
    glEnd();
    output(235.0,880.0,"Time");
    glRasterPos2f(235.0,855.0);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'1');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,':');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'3');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,':');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,' ');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'P');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'M');
}

void Time2 ()
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.8,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(230.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,845.0);
        glVertex2f(230.0,845.0);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(230.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,845.0);
        glVertex2f(230.0,845.0);
    glEnd();
    output(235.0,880.0,"Time");
    glRasterPos2f(235.0,855.0);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'1');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,':');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'4');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'5');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,':');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,' ');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'P');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'M');
}

void Time3 ()
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.8,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(230.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,845.0);
        glVertex2f(230.0,845.0);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(230.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,893.0);
        glVertex2f(355.0,845.0);
        glVertex2f(230.0,845.0);
    glEnd();
    output(235.0,880.0,"Time");
    glRasterPos2f(235.0,855.0);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'2');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,':');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,':');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'0');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,' ');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'P');
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'M');
}

void Draw ()
{
    glDrawPixels(n,m,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, image);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.8,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(8.0, 893.0);
        glVertex2f(210.0, 893.0);
        glVertex2f(210.0, 645.0);
        glVertex2f(8.0, 645.0);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(8.0, 893.0);
        glVertex2f(210.0, 893.0);
        glVertex2f(210.0, 645.0);
        glVertex2f(8.0, 645.0);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    output(13,880,"Legend");
    output(13,860,"* - Custer's Headquarters Unit");
    output(13,847,"F - Custer's Command");
    output(13,834,"C - Custer's Command");
    output(13,821,"E - Custer's Command");
    output(13,808,"I - Custer's Command");
    output(13,795,"L - Custer's Command");
    output(13,782,"A - Reno's Command");
    output(13,769,"M - Reno's Command");
    output(13,756,"G - Reno's Command");
    output(13,743,"H - Benteen's Command");
    output(13,730,"D - Benteen's Command");
    output(13,717,"K - Benteen's Command");
    output(13,704,"B - Packtrain Guard");
    output(13,691,"Packtrain - Blank Cavalry Unit");
    output(13,678,"G - Gall (Hunkpapa Warchief)");
    output(13,665,"C - Crazy Horse (Oglala Warchief");
    output(13,652,"IU(n) - 34 Blank Indian Units");
}

void myInit (void)
{
     glClearColor ( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 , 1.0);
     glColor3f ( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
     glPointSize ( 4.0 );
     glMatrixMode ( GL_PROJECTION );
     glLoadIdentity ( );
     gluOrtho2D ( 0.0, 400.0, 0.0, 400.0 );
}

void myreshape(int h, int w)
{
 glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluOrtho2D(0.0, (GLfloat) n, 0.0, (GLfloat) m);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glViewport(0,0,h,w);
}

void display(void)
{

glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
glRasterPos2i(0,0);
    Draw();
    if (onMouse == 1)
        Time1();
    if (onMouse == 2)
        Time2();
    if (onMouse == 3)
        Time3();

    glFlush ();
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
FILE *fd;
int k, nm;
char c;
char b[70];
float s;
char red, green, blue;
int x, y;

fd = fopen("map.ppm", "r");
if(fd == 0)
{
    exit(0);
}


fscanf(fd, "%s", b);
if((b[0] != 'P') || (b[1] != '6'))
{
    printf("%s is not a PPM file!\n", b);
    exit(0);
}

fscanf(fd, "%c", &c);

fscanf(fd, "%c", &c);
while(c == '#')
{
    fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]", b);
    printf("%s\n", b);
    fscanf(fd, "%c", &c);
    printf("%c", c);
}

ungetc(c,fd);

fscanf(fd, "%d %d %d", &n, &m, &k);

printf("%d rows  %d colums  max value = %d\n", n, m, k);

nm = n*m;

image = (int*)malloc(3*sizeof(GLint)*nm);

s = 255./k;

for(x = 0; x < m; x++)
{
    for(y = n-1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
       fscanf(fd, "%c", &red);
       fscanf(fd, "%c", &green);
       fscanf(fd, "%c", &blue);

       image[3*nm - 3*(x*n +y) -3] = green;
       image[3*nm - 3*(x*n +y) -2] = blue;
       image[3*nm - 3*(x*n +y) -1] = red;

    }
}


glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(n,m);
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
glutCreateWindow("Little BigHorn");
glutReshapeFunc(myreshape);
glutMouseFunc(mouseClicks);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_SCALE, s);
glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_SCALE, s);
glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_SCALE, s);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_TRUE);
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
myInit ( );

    glutMainLoop ( );

}
```

Comment: Wow this code isn't sane. First, your `Time2` and `Time3` functions are almost identical; it is likely you just don't see the difference. Second, what is supposed to happen after third and any subsequent clicks? Because in your code, - the answer is 'nothing'. And finally third - why on earth would you clone functions in such barbaric manner and not at least make one function for each object, if not better?

Comment: This is my first time using openGL. I was just experimenting. The reason all the time functions are similar is because I am trying to change/draw over the polygon with a same size polygon but a different time. When the program starts, the polygon displays 1:30:00 PM. When I click the first time, the polygon is replaced with a same size polygon with the time of 1:45:00 PM. When I click for a second time the polygon disappears. I am trying to loop the mouse click so I can keep replacing the polygon with a different time each time I click the left button

Comment: No you're not even trying to loop. It is just `onMouse++`, always. Even more, it switches on both key down **and** key up (`state` parameter in mouse callback), so single click triggers two events, essentially skipping `Time2` and switching to `Time3`.

Comment: So with me changing it to "if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)" how can I loop the clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Mouse click callback should be implemented e.g. that way:

```
void mouseClicks(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP) {
        if(++onMouse > 3) {
            onMouse = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Next time I *highly* recommend pinning down a problem instead of posting wall of code, without clear description of problem itself. While this site is indeed for questions and answers, how will you write code next time if even on simplest problem you getting stuck? You seeing that your drawing is presumably incorrect; what it depends upon? `onMouse` value. What value does it have right now, when you see a problem? (at the very least you could `printf` it, but I recommend start using debugger; it is much much more awesome). Is this value supposed to be acceptable? Where it gets changed? Is change correct? That's all the questions you really should ask yourself when you see a problem, or don't expect any improvement.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I cannot expect to better myself if I cannot pinpoint the issue and ask myself simple questions. I really appreciate the help and the advice. Sorry for the wall of code as well.